# Using c++11 legacy library in a C++17 project: compiler & linker problems

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, linker, c++17

I am working in a project based on C++17 and have to rely on a library built with C++11 (or older). Problems arise from the fact that several structs have been removed for good from `std` with C++17.
Note that I am *building the legacy library from source*!

The problems:

- If I am building the library with C++11 and use it in the C++17 project, the linker won't find the correct implementations (e.g. `string`). That makes sense, since listing the library symbols I can see it references `std::c++11::basic_string`.
- If I am trying to build the library with C++17, the compiler does not find the missing C++03 structs (e.g. `ptr_fun`). Again makes sense, as they are not part of the C++17 stdlib.
- If I am trying to build the library with C++17 but include headers from C++11, everything explodes. Makes sense since the headers are not compatible.

Long story short, I do not see how to easily solve this. Technically, since I am able to build the library from source, there should be no definitive reason why I cannot use it with any other project. What's the best practice for this?

I am using Linux with clang for this. The question should be the same with  any compiler and OS though.

Comment: This is not really a thing you can resolve. If you're statically linking to a library, that library and yours need to agree on the definition of all of the objects they both rely on.

Comment: Agreed, there is no easy fix. But probably best to move forward rather than backward.
You are probably best off getting the maximum list of errors when compiling with c++17, and working out a strategy to address each one, for example by using std::function as the auto return type from your own  ptr_fun. Then cost up the actual fix, and perhaps back off to c++14 as a compromise?

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments! I'm still really surprised there is no c++17 to 11 fallback to make common libs compile with c++17 as this has to be a very common issue. IMHO this should be a macro in any std library implementation.

Comment: @BM I had a similar situation sometime ago. I tried many things. Finally ended up building DLL taking care of boundary crossing scenarios. For example std::string (c++11) in exe was passed as foo::String in Dll which was just a wrapper over actual std::string (c++98). Similar thing for std::vector. I did not implement everything, just the ones I needed.

Comment: I did not really find an acceptable solution for any of this. But I am going to mention for others that feature toggle macros __do__ exist for some C++ std structs in llvm's libc++ project: `_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_AUTO_PTR` for example.